# Paypal Code ONLY working in IE

Tags: paypal

Here is my code, this does not work in Chrome, Safari, FF or Opera.  ONLY IE, imagine that. Can anyone help troubleshoot?

```
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="3H5E29L5LR5UN">
                <table>
                <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Choose a Membership">Choose a Membership</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
                    <option value="Individual">Individual $25.00 USD</option>
                    <option value="Students/Seniors with valid id">Students/Seniors with valid id $12.50 USD</option>
                    <option value="Group 2-5 members">Group 2-5 members $62.50 USD</option>
                    <option value="Group 6-10 members">Group 6-10 members $125.00 USD</option>
                </select> </td></tr>
                </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything IE-specific here...

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Because binding/attaching events can be IE specific.

Comment: Yeah, it is weird, it works in IE but no other browser.

Comment: feel free to test http://triadindie.org/application/paypal.php

Comment: You are not closing any input tags :) `<input ...>` should be `<input .../>`

Comment: @Silvermind: Not in HTML, it shouldn't.  HTML 5 doesn't require it outside of XHTML (but allows it, only cause XHTML weenies would go through all kinds of withdrawal if they had to part with their self-closing tags).  And it's outright invalid in HTML 4.01 and earlier.

Comment: @SethHall Your Paypal form "works" for me in Chrome and FF, as in, I'm successfully directed to Paypal.

Comment: @cHao Didn't know that, thanks. I think it is more readable though if they were closed. ;)

Comment: Works for me in FF11 and Chromium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED THE ISSUE!!!

I am using the 960 grid system and for some reason when I add

```
class="grid_anything pullorpush_anything"
```

the anchor links become inactive

I removed the `pullorpush_anything` and all is well.

Maybe I should use `prefix` instead.

Thanks to everyone for all the feedback